# Can't connect to server using rtmfp

Tags: rtmfp, adobe-media-server

How can I connect to my server using rtmfp?

I can do this:

```
var test:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
trace('trying to connect');
test.connect("rtmp://[server]/chat");
test.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,function(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
    trace(event.info.code);
});
```

And get `NetConnection.Connect.Success`

But when I do this:

```
var test:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
trace('trying to connect');
test.connect("rtmfp://[server]/chat");
test.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,function(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
    trace(event.info.code);
});
```

It fails after a long time.

I'm connecting to my own Adobe Media Server v.5.0.3. All TCP and UDP ports are open.

`RTMFP enable` is set to `true` in `[ams root]\conf\_defaultRoot_\Adaptor.xml`

http://cc.rtmfp.net/ gives me back:

- no
- yes
- yes
- no
- no
- yes
- yes
- yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason for your sample to not work. Maybe you've mistaken some configuration or your firewall is blocking the UDP port.

Do you see "Adobe Media Server" listening on port 1935 if you call the following command :

```
netstat -a -b -p UDP
```

Why don't you try [MonaServer](http://www.monaserver.ovh/)? It works without configuration and it's an open source project. Here is a [chat sample](https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/tree/master/chat) working with RTMFP or WebSocket.